# How to add fallback values for methods of the related model in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Consider the two following models. First one, the Post model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function category(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class)->withDefault();
    }
}
```

Next one, the Category model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class Category extends Model
{
    public function url()
    {
        return 'here.we/generate/category/url';
    }

    public function posts(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

If `$post` contains the valid instance of a model `Post`, then calling `$post->category` will get the related instance of a `Category` model or `null` if it's not set.

If somewhere in a blade template, the `$post->category->url()` will get called, the blade will output **Error: Call to a member function url() on null** in case if `$post->category` is `null`.

I want to handle the aforementioned case via the model class if possible, not having to add an extra conditional check to each block that uses the method, as it adds excess clutter to the codebase, which should be avoided if possible in order to follow the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

I haven't found anything related to this question in Laravel docs, so I'm asking a question here.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public function category(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class)->withDefault([
                      'id' => 1,
                      'name' => 'ABC',
               ]);
    }

you can pass a default array in with default to add fallback
```